# Service will be 'unavailable Saturday' vs '...unavailable on Saturday'

Tags: prefixes, dates, negative-prefixes

I want to perfect this system message the most I can and am over-thinking the use of the proper words.

Is it better to say "Email will be unavailable Saturday 12/29 from 5 PM to 9 PM" or "Email will be unavailable on Saturday 12/29 from 5 PM to 9 PM."

Our client chose the message so I don't want to alter it too much which would make him think his English was bad, but I wish to use the proper way of letting the users know WHEN Email will be unavailable.

So is it 'unavailable Saturday 12/29' or 'unavailable on Saturday 12/29'?

Answer (score 0):

> So is it 'unavailable Saturday 12/29' or 'unavailable on Saturday 12/29'?

and

> Our client chose the message so I don't want to alter it too much

It does not need to be corrected - both are fine for a system message.

---

For what it is worth, I would use "unavailable Saturday 12/29".

According to some Computer Human Interaction (CHI) articles I've read, you should *generally* use the "shorter is better" rule *with system messages* because the user is more likely to read a shorter message.
(This does not imply that they are *likely* to read them).

The advice assumes that the shorter message is as clear as the original - which applies here.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the context, you may need to alter the email part.

For the sentence part, the correct way is:

> Email will be unavailable **on** Saturday 12/29 from 5PM to 9PM

Usually when talking about days of the week, we say we are **on** this day.